# Is there a way to validate the build process parameters when editing the build definition in TFS?

Tags: tfs, build-process, tfsbuild

I tried looking on Google to see if this was possible but failed in getting results.

I have a build process file which requires some custom parameters to be set before executing the build.

I was wondering if there was a way to validate what was being entered for the custom parameters when editing the build definition in the 'Process' tab?

For example, I have two separate parameters which holds different file names in the same folder location. The build definition then has functionality to swap those file names around.

When editing these parameters, lets say the user enters the same name in both fields accidentally, is there are way to prompt the user (there and then) that (s)he needs to enter different file names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way through implementing a Custom Parameter Editor, as described in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2010/01/18/tfs-2010-custom-process-parameters-part-3-custom-editors.aspx). Shortly, you write some custom WinForm code to input and validate parameters.
If you go through this route consider

- managing client side customization (test, deploy, update)
- builds can be queued through other means (e.g. command line) and this code check the values only in Visual Studio
- doubling the check in the workflow itself as ChrisBint suggested

Answer (score 1):

You can write a serverside plugin which Implements the [ISubscriber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.server.isubscriber.aspx) interface and the EventType (SubscribedTypes)  [BuildDefinitionChangingEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.server.builddefinitionchangingevent.aspx).

You'll get the old version of the BuildDefinition and the new one.
This is a decision point, so you can prevent the BuildDefinition from getting changed.

To get some idea what an ISubscriber is and how to implement it, have a look at these 2 pages:
http://vgaltes.com/index.php/2013/04/14/create-a-team-foundation-server-event-handler/
http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2010/10/27/devleoping-and-debugging-server-side-event-handlers-in-tfs-2010.aspx

The TFS Server API does provide events for different kind of actions triggered by a user or process. You can subscribe to those events and execute actions. There are 2 different types: **Notifications** and **Decision Points**. The difference between them is that a decision point is able to cancel an action. For example you can prevent a source control checkin.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'You'll get the old version of the BuildDefinition and the new one. This is a decision point, so you can prevent the BuildDefinition from getting changed' - may you expand on this. Also I find 'You can write a serverside plugin which Implements the ISubscriber interface and the EventType (SubscribedTypes) BuildDefinitionChangingEvent' very interesting, can you explain more in detail how to go about doing this?

Comment: I've added more details to my posting

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not.

The build definition will limit the input only to the parameter type and no further validation is done. The only place to validate this would be in the activity itself. While this would not alert the user at the point of editing the build, you can in theory fail the build if they matched.